# How do I create my own custom hosts file?

Tags: 14.04, networking

For some specific reasons I don't want to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and that is why I needed to create my own hosts file in suppose `~/hosts` and use it for all IP to HOSTNAME mapping along with the system's `/etc/hosts` file. How will I be able to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the environment variable `HOSTALIASES`:

1. Define the environment variable `HOSTALIASES`

   ```
   export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
   ```
2. Create your private `hosts` file and add a test entry

   ```
   echo 'myprivategoogle www.google.com' > ~/.hosts
   ```
3. Start a test

   ```
   curl myprivategoogle
   ```

   **without** the entry in `~/.hosts` you would get

   ```
   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myprivategoogle
   ```

   **with** the entry you have

   ```
   <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
   <TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
   <H1>302 Moved</H1>
   The document has moved
   <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
   </BODY></HTML>
   ```

Comment: I had one more query. This method assumes that the keys are present in '~/.ssh' folder when I have my keys at a separate place and I have also defined it in the '~/.ssh/config' file. But still it does not pick up the keys from there. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry, not in the comments, Please ask a new question. **;)**

Comment: It does not seem to work anymore