# Override default 'HOSTALIASES' behaviour

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh

I followed the method of creating my own custom hosts file as suggested here [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/701915/286994). It works fine.

But the problem is it expects your public and private keys to be in the `~/.ssh` folder with the name `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` respectively and I actually have my keys elsewhere as defined in my `~/.ssh/config` file.

So if I want to use this method, I have to copy the contents of my public and private keys which are at a different location to  `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`.

So how do I override this default behaviour of `HOSTALIASES`?

Comment: What does ssh authentication have to do with custom host files? As a wild guess, are you trying to set up a machine-to-machine trust via an NFS-shared home directory?

Comment: Yes. I am basically setting up a Hadoop cluster and I don't want to edit /etc/hosts file for some reasons.